# Loading the data to the session without delaying Loading the Page c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know, in my current project after the login, there are certain data that I want to load to the session.

So I wrote it on the JsonResult and used Ajax call on the Index page.

But it waits to load the page while data is processed to the session.

Is there any way I can show the page while running the ajax call?

```
@{ List <Asp_PASMVC.ViewModels.NewsShareViewModel> smcNews = Session["smcNews"] as List <Asp_PASMVC.ViewModels.NewsShareViewModel>; if (smcNews == null) { smcNews = new List <Asp_PASMVC.ViewModels.NewsShareViewModel>(); } else { var RsmcNews = smcNews.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate); } }
      <link href="~/csss/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <body onload="GetData();">
        <br />
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xl-6">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="card tryal-gradient">
                      <div class="card-body tryal row">
                        <div class="col-xl-7 col-sm-6">
                          <h2 id="demo">Welcome to the new PAS</h2>
                          <span>Welcome to the paperless approval system</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-5 col-sm-6">
                          <img src="~/images/chart.png" alt="" class="sd-shape">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <script>
                    const time = new Date().getHours();
                    let greeting;
                    if (time < 12) {
                      greeting = "Good Morning";
                    } else if (time < 15) {
                      greeting = "Good Afternoon";
                    } else {
                      greeting = "Good Evening";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting + "  @(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity)?.FindFirst("
                    EmpName ")?.Value.ToString())";
                  </script>
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header border-0 flex-wrap">
                        <div class="card-header border-0">
                          <div>
                            <h4 class="fs-20 font-w700">Announcements</h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--Section Tiles-->
              <div class="col-xl-6">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-body d-flex px-4  justify-content-between">
                            <div>
                              <div class="">
                                <h2 class="fs-32 font-w700" id="MyRequests">0</h2>
                                <span class="fs-18 font-w500 d-block">My Requests</span>
                                <a href="@Url.Action(" Index","AppRequests")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-5x" style="color:forestgreen"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-body d-flex px-4  justify-content-between">
                            <div>
                              <div class="">
                                <h2 class="fs-32 font-w700" id="pendingRequests">0</h2>
                                <span class="fs-18 font-w500 d-block">Pending Requests</span>
                                <a href="@Url.Action(" Index","PendingRequestM")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-bell fa-5x" style="color:blueviolet"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-body d-flex px-4  justify-content-between">
                            <div>
                              <div class="">
                                <h2 class="fs-32 font-w700" id="AttendetRequests">0</h2>
                                <span class="fs-18 font-w500 d-block">Attended Requests</span>
                                <a href="@Url.Action(" Index","RequestHistory")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher fa-5x" style="color:sandybrown"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-body d-flex px-4  justify-content-between">
                            <div>
                              <div class="">
                                <h2 class="fs-32 font-w700" id="CancelledRequests">0</h2>
                                <span class="fs-18 font-w500 d-block">Cancelled Requests</span>
                                <a href="@Url.Action(" Index", "AppRequests" )" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <i class="fas fa-ban fa-5x" style="color:#ff0000"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Recent Approvals-->
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header border-0">
                        <div>
                          <h4 class="fs-20 font-w700">Recent Approvals</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div> @foreach (var Data in ViewBag.suggestList) { <div class="card-body px-0">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between recent-emails">
                          <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="profile-k">
                              <img src="~/Theam/img/Request.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="ms-3">
                              <h4 class="fs-18 font-w500">@Data.RequestHeading</h4>
                              <span class="font-w400 d-block">@Data.RequestedDate <br>@Data.RequestType </span>
                              <span class="badge badge-success">Approved</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="material-icons floating-btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" Create", "AppRequests" )'">+</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetData() {
          getIndexData();
        }

        function getIndexData() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/IndexData',
            success: function(data) {
              if (data == true) {} else {}
            },
            error: function() {
              //alert('Something went wrong, Try Later');
            }
          });
        }
      </script>
```

This is the JsonResult

```
public JsonResult IndexData() {
    
   int Id = int.Parse(UsrIDTS);

   int CurrDepId = (from e in db.CreateEmployee where e.Id == Id select new {
     e.DepId
   }).First().DepId;
   int CostCenterId = (from c in db.CreateDepartment where c.Id == CurrDepId select new {
     c.Cost_Center_Id
   }).First().Cost_Center_Id;
   DateTime Fivedaysago = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-5);

   List < int > ReqTypeDropDown = (from a in db.AppRequest join e in db.CreateEmployee on a.Create_By equals e.Id join d in db.CreateDepartment on e.DepId equals d.Id join c in db.PaymentVoucher on a.Id equals c.Req_Id join p in db.PaymentVoucherExpenDetails on c.Id equals p.Payvouch_Id where e.DepId != CurrDepId && p.CostCenterId == CostCenterId & a.Status == true && a.Created_Date >= Fivedaysago orderby a.Created_Date descending select a.Id).Distinct().ToList();

   List < AppRequest > MainR = db.AppRequest.Where(m => ReqTypeDropDown.Any(r => r.Equals(m.Id))).ToList();

   List < AppRequest > MainRequest = MainR.Where(y => y.Status == true).ToList();

   List < CostCenterNewsfeedModel > News = new List < CostCenterNewsfeedModel > ();

   DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

   var ComIDVal = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity)?.FindFirst("CompanyID")?.Value;

   int comId = int.Parse(ComIDVal); // need to check

   List < M_Employee > EmpList = db.CreateEmployee.Where(x => x.Status == true && x.CompanyId == comId).ToList();
   List < SelectListItem > EmpDropDown = EmpList.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
     Text = x.EmpName + " Emp No:" + x.EmpNo, Value = x.Id.ToString()
   }).ToList();

   List < NewsShareViewModel > smcNews = new List < NewsShareViewModel > ();

   smcNews = (from n in db.NewsShare join e in db.CreateEmployee on n.Created_By equals e.Id join d in db.CreateDepartment on e.DepId equals d.Id where n.CreatedDate > twoDaysAgo select new NewsShareViewModel {
     Id = n.Id,
       UserName = e.EmpName,
       Department = d.Department,
       Message = n.Comment,
       UserId = n.Created_By,
       CreatedDate = n.CreatedDate.ToString()
   }).ToList();

   List < M_CostCenter > Costcenter = db.CreateCostCenter.Where(c => c.Status == true).ToList();
   List < SelectListItem > CostCenterDrop = Costcenter.Select(cd => new SelectListItem {
     Text = cd.CostCenter, Value = cd.Id.ToString()
   }).ToList();

   Session["Costcenter"] = CostCenterDrop;
   Session["NewsFeed"] = News;
   Session["smcNews"] = smcNews;
   Session["EmployeeList"] = EmpDropDown;

   return Json(new {
     Success = false
   }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

 }
```

Comment: where you call `getIndexData` function?, put whole html code

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh Hi! I updated the question with the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I did this change to the code. I tried after loading the page calling Ajax. So far It's worked.

```
 $(function () {
   setTimeout(getIndexData, 5000);
 });
```